# Create FTPS server without giving out my IP address?

Tags: networking, ftp, filezilla

I am creating an FTPS server with FileZilla, and I want to have some other people access it from wherever they are. The issue is, I don't want to give them my IP address. Is there a way I can do this without giving out my IP address?

P.S: Sorry, my English is not very good. And I'm very new to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. They need the IP address to connect. Even if you just give them a domain name address, like ftp.example.com, they can use tools such as nslookup to find the IP address.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. One last question, how would I go about creating a domain name address like that? (preferrably for free)

Comment: There are a few sites that you can set up dynamic forwarding on, but offhand, I don't know any of their names.

Comment: @ditheredtransparency: [http://www.noip.com/](http://www.noip.com/) is free (monthly conformation required).

Answer (score 0):

You can run the server via a [Tor hidden service](https://www.torproject.org/docs/hidden-services.html.en), and give them just the .onion address.

Comment: How would I do that? Is there a tutorial or something I could use?

Comment: https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en